# How to retrieve user info with Azure AD scopes and oidc-client.js?

Tags: azure-active-directory, oidc-client-js

I'm confused how I can get access tokens and user info details when using azure ad scopes with oidc-client.js.

I have the following scope against my app in the portal...

[image]

I then have my user manager settings set up as follows....

```js
var settings: UserManagerSettings = {
    authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}`,
    client_id: clientId,
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/authcallback",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/authcallback",
    response_type: "token id_token",
    scope: `api://${clientId}/access_user_data openid`,
    popup_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/authcallback",
    silent_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000/authcallback",
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    loadUserInfo: true,
    metadata: {
        userinfo_endpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo",
        authorization_endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`,
        issuer: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/v2.0`,
        jwks_uri: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/discovery/v2.0/keys`
    }
};
```

When I login with `signinRedirect` I get an `access_token` returned to my callback, however the call to `https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo` fails with unauthorized when doing `getUser()`.

```
oidc-client.min.js:1 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/oidc/userinfo 401 (Unauthorized)
```

The access token does appear to work with my api that requires the `api://${clientId}/access_user_data` scope.

The discovery document [here](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration) lists the following available scopes

```json
"scopes_supported": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "email",
    "offline_access"
]
```

Which I thought would have worked as I am also including the `openid` scope. Note that if I only have the `openid` scope like so `scope: "openid"`, `getUser()` works, however it doesn't have the scope I need for calling my api.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: An access token only works against one API, so you need two tokens in your case I think.

Comment: But you should be able to have multiple scopes in a single token shouldn't you?

Comment: Yes, but only for a single API.

Comment: The token is unique, and one token can only call one api.

Comment: So user info is considered a separate api even though it's all wrapped up in the same app registration? Does that mean I need to maintain 2 separate instances of UserManager? That doesn't seem ideal....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the Same issue after some research tried setting loadUserInfo to false that resolved my problem can please try the same

Comment: Thanks. It works in the sense `getUser()` no longer fails, then I can go on to call my api. It's missing various claims though, such as `email`, `family_name`, `given_name` etc that I get when I define the scope as just `openid` in `UserManagerSettings`. I hoped I could get everything in one token but I guess not.

Comment: Yes you can get the remaining things bypassing "profile", "email" in the scope